# How to prove that $f$ surjective, if $g$ is injective and $g \circ f$ is surjective?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

$X, Y$ and $Z$ are non-empty sets. $f : X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$ are functions.

Prove that $f$ is surjective, if $g$ is injective and $g \circ f$ is surjective.

I'm aware of the surjective and injective definitions, but how would I prove that $f$ is surjective under the given conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ surjective :

Need to show that for    $y \in Y$ there is a $x \in X$ with:

$f(x) = y.$

Let $y \in Y$ :  $g(y)= z.$

Since $g \circ f$ is surjective:

There is a $x \in X$ with $g(f(x)) = z$.

$z= g(y)= g(f(x)).$

Since $g$ is injective:

$y = f(x)$, I.e.

for every $y \in Y$ there is a $x \in X$ with $y=f(x).$

Hence $f$ is surjective.